# Web3.js doesn't fire event callbacks anymore

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

I have a small dapp that uses web3.js to interact with a contract.  I have one event listener:

```
let activateEvent = nexusContract.events.Activate({ _member: defaultAccount })

activateEvent.watch((error, result) => {
  console.log(error, result)
})
```

However, the event callback never fires.  I've checked it on the Solidity end of the things, and the smart contract is definitely firing events.  What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried this syntax too:

```
activateEvent.on('data', (error, result) => console.log(error, result))
```

But to not avail.

The version of web3.js I'm using is 1.0.0-beta.34, and I'm using with MetaMask on the mainnet.

Comment: Are you trying to get a receipt, or transactionHash ?

Comment: what is the provider that you are using? You should use web socket provider